# How to set focus on an SWT TableItem

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I have an add Button, which adds rows to an SWT table and i implemented TableEditor to edit the rows.

```
Button button = new Button(composite, SWT.NONE);
  button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
     @Override
     public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
                }
  });
```

and this is the piece of code for table creation

```
table = new Table(composite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
  table.setBounds(0, 0, 240, 160);
  toolkit.adapt(table);
  toolkit.paintBordersFor(table);
  table.setHeaderVisible(true);
  table.setLinesVisible(true);
```

When the user hits the add button, a row is created allowing the user to edit. But from a user point of view, its not visible that row is created or not, until and unless he selects that row and editor is enabled.

So can you please suggest on how to set focus on the newly added TableItem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Table.setSelection() and Table.showItem() API.